# SQL ORDER BY CASE + DESC

Tags: sql, graphql, graphql-js

I need to sort my data using ORDER BY CASE in two steps: First, I need to reverse the sort with using "DESC", and after that, this sorting, need to sort alphabetically

I represent such code like this

```
ORDER BY
  
    CASE WHEN sort_param = 'HIGH_TO_LOW'
      THEN goal_progress DESC //reverse data
      THEN LOWER(s.title) END, //sort alphabetically
...
```

But this doesn't work because of syntax error

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you split each condition into a separate `case`:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN sort_param = 'HIGH_TO_LOW' THEN goal_progress END),
        LOWER(s.title)
```

Comment: I will clarify. If the values of the first sort are equal, then it is necessary to sort alphabetically. Does your decision take this into account?

Comment: @Miltosh . . . I modified the answer.